# manipulation on wave equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, physics, wave-equation

Given $a_{ij}:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$ and suppose that $a_0>0$ which $\sum_{ij}a_{ij}\xi_i\xi_j \geq a_o|\xi|^2$, $\forall x\in \mathbb{R^n}, \xi\in \mathbb{R^n}$. Considering
$$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial t^2}u(x,t)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(a_{ij}(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}(x,t))$$ I need to prove that, if $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R^n}\times [0,T)), T>0$ is a compact support function then
$$E(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}\big[(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t})^2+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}(a_{ij}(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j}(x,t)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(x,t))\big]$$ is a constant for all $t\in[0,T)$

My attempt: we need to show that $E'(t)=0, \forall t\in[0,T)$. Then, I multiplicated the PDE by $\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$, then the first term can be manipulated and be $(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t})^2$. After this, the other term seems doesn't help in the manipulation (I think that I'm not seeing the manipulation). Some hint?

Comment: \begin{align} E'(t) &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} 2u_{t}u_{tt} + \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}[(u_{t})_{x_{j}} u_{x_{i}} + u_{x_{j}}(u_{t})_{x_{i}}] dx \\ &\underbrace{=}_{\text{IBP}} \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}[u_{t} u_{x_{i}} \lvert_{\mathbb{R}} + u_{x_{j}}u_{t} \lvert_{\mathbb{R}}] + \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} 2u_{t}u_{tt} - \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}[u_{t} u_{x_{i},x_{j}} + u_{x_{j},x_{i}} u_{t}] dx \\ &= \underbrace{0}_{\text{compact support}} + \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} 2u_{t} \underbrace{\left( u_{tt} - \sum_{i,j} a_{ij}u_{x_{i},x_{j}} \right)}_{= \ 0 \  \text{from the PDE}} dx \\ &= 0\end{align} and hence $E$ is constant.

Comment: why is =0 from the PDE? $a_{ij}$ depends on x.